# How to run shell scripts in a ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net, shell, rsync

I need to use rsync do some file transfer, and want this script to be integrate into a web interface system with other stuff.

My idea is just easy like having a upload button to upload files, then another button to run the script which rsync the target files. How should I implement this? Since rsync may requires at least a cygwin or another UNIX host. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much access you have to the box, but my general inclination on things like this is to implement it as a request queue/execution system. Meaning the app takes the upload, makes a command and stashes it somewhere than an offline process executes and returns the results. Big advantage here being you don't need to monkey around with permissions for a web app to be able to, say, securely execute shell commands.